# Disable warnings from .tags files

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

I have a project that makes heavy use of Qt and want its documentation to link to the relevant Qt documentation.
To this end, the doxyfile of my project adds all of Qt's `.tags` files as `TAGFILES` which works as intended.

To my surprise I get many warnings that stem from Qt's `.tags` files and look like this:

```
/usr/share/doc/qt/qtcore/qtcore.tags:1: Warning: parameters of member QObject::QObject are not (all) documented
/usr/share/doc/qt/qtcore/qtcore.tags:1: Warnung: parameters of member QObject::event are not (all) documented
```

Since they pertain to a third party library out of my control, I don't want to be informed about them. 
Setting `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = NO` gets rid of them. Unfortunately, they are also muted for my code, where I'd like to get these warnings.

There seems to be no option to disable warnings only for `.tags` files.
How can I achieve this separation between my code and theirs?

**EDIT**

Trying to `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = /*.tags *.tags` changes nothing.

Comment: Could this be something like you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334010/is-it-possible-to-choose-which-doxygen-warning-to-show ?

Comment: @BobMorane I'd like to include the Doxygen run into my CMake build process which is handled by QtCreator. I am afraid that filtering via handwritten shell code is not an option in this case.

Comment: I made a pull request to add this feature: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 1.8.14 (commit [aac84d5](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/aac84d5624b96d8937ff543ab8724c269b8726ab)) the warnings on `.tags` files have been disabled.